# ReadBytes with DataReader in Windows Store app

Tags: .net, serial-port, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

I have a little challenge with my code. 
I earlier programmed an application in .NET 2.0, that reading write and read/from a TCP based SerialPort Device Server (Moxa NPort).

It worked great in .NET 2.0, but when converted to .NET 4.5 and Windows Store App I need to use DataReader/Writer instread of NetworkStream.Read/Write.

I have managed to make the code write to the device and I can see at the log from the device server that it answers as well but the app says out of bound. So its a problem inside my code apparently.

Here is my code: In the buttom i have attached the old .NET 2.0 code.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

### New Code

```
    Try
        If SendCommand IsNot Nothing Then
            'status.Text = "Forsøger at sende data ..."

            Dim StreamWriter As New DataWriter(ClientSocket.OutputStream)

            Dim outNumBytes As Integer = 0
            Dim outStream As Byte() = New Byte((SendCommand.Length + 1) \ 3 - 1) {}

            For outNumBytes = 0 To outStream.Length - 1
                outStream(outNumBytes) = Byte.Parse(SendCommand.Substring(3 * outNumBytes, 2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
            Next

            StreamWriter.WriteBytes(outStream)
            Await StreamWriter.StoreAsync()

            StreamWriter.DetachStream()
            StreamWriter.Dispose()

            'status.Text = "Data afsendt (" & SendCommand & ")"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        returnError = "Fejl ved afsendelse af data: " & ex.Message
        ErrorHandling(returnError)

        ClientSocket.Dispose()
        ClientSocket = Nothing

        Return returnData
        Exit Function
    End Try

    Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(50)

    Try
        'status.Text = "Forsøger at modtage data ..."

        Dim StreamReader As New DataReader(ClientSocket.InputStream)
        StreamReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial

        Dim inStream(0) As Byte
        Dim inText As New StringBuilder(inStream.Length * 2)

        Await StreamReader.LoadAsync(256)
        StreamReader.ReadBytes(inStream)

        For Each inByte As Byte In inStream
            inText.AppendFormat("{0:X2}:", inByte)
        Next

        returnData = inText.ToString()

        StreamReader.DetachStream()
        StreamReader.Dispose()

        'status.Text = "Data modtaget (" & strReceived & ")"
    Catch ex As Exception
        returnError = "Fejl ved modtagelse af data: " & ex.Message
        ErrorHandling(returnError)

        ClientSocket.Dispose()
        ClientSocket = Nothing

        Return returnData
        Exit Function
    End Try
```

### Old Code

```
Public Function SendReceive(ByVal SendCommand As String)
    Dim returnCode As String = Nothing

    '//Write
    Dim outText As String = SendCommand
    Dim outNumBytes As Integer = 0
    Dim outStream As Byte() = New Byte((outText.Length + 1) \ 3 - 1) {}

    If NetworkStream.CanWrite Then

        Try
            For outNumBytes = 0 To outStream.Length - 1
                outStream(outNumBytes) = Byte.Parse(outText.Substring(3 * outNumBytes, 2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
            Next

            NetworkStream.Write(outStream, 0, outNumBytes)

        Catch ex As Exception
            returnCode = "Error: " & ex.Message

            Return returnCode
            Exit Function
        End Try

    End If

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)

    '//Read
    Dim inStream(0) As Byte
    Dim inText As New StringBuilder(inStream.Length * 2)

    Do While NetworkStream.CanRead And NetworkStream.DataAvailable

        Try
            NetworkStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)

            For Each inByte As Byte In inStream
                inText.AppendFormat("{0:X2}:", inByte)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            returnCode = "Error: " & ex.Message

            Return returnCode
            Exit Function
        End Try

    Loop

    returnCode = inText.ToString()
    If returnCode > Nothing Then returnCode = returnCode.Substring(0, returnCode.Length - 1)

    Return returnCode
End Function
```

Changed: Using a Do While StreamReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0 getting it to read one byte at the time until the end of stream.

```
        Dim StreamReader As New DataReader(ClientSocket.InputStream)
        StreamReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial

        If srvMode = True Then
            Dim strReceivedBytes As String = Await StreamReader.LoadAsync(256)
            returnData = StreamReader.ReadString(strReceivedBytes)
        Else
            Dim inStream(0) As Byte
            Dim inText As New StringBuilder(inStream.Length * 2)

            Await StreamReader.LoadAsync(256)

            Do While StreamReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0
                StreamReader.ReadBytes(inStream)

                For Each inByte As Byte In inStream
                    inText.AppendFormat("{0:X2}:", inByte)
                Next
            Loop

            returnData = inText.ToString()
```

Comment: Does the exception give you the line where you're getting the index out of bounds error?

Comment: No not specified line. But i know its in the Reading section becouse it is sending to the device fine. My guess is that it not receiving any bytes from the stream. And therefore fails in the Array.

Comment: I got it to work by adding the ReadBytes in a loop:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed: Using a Do While StreamReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0 getting it to read one byte at the time until the end of stream.

```
    Dim StreamReader As New DataReader(ClientSocket.InputStream)
    StreamReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial

    If srvMode = True Then
        Dim strReceivedBytes As String = Await StreamReader.LoadAsync(256)
        returnData = StreamReader.ReadString(strReceivedBytes)
    Else
        Dim inStream(0) As Byte
        Dim inText As New StringBuilder(inStream.Length * 2)

        Await StreamReader.LoadAsync(256)

        Do While StreamReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0
            StreamReader.ReadBytes(inStream)

            For Each inByte As Byte In inStream
                inText.AppendFormat("{0:X2}:", inByte)
            Next
        Loop

        returnData = inText.ToString()
```